# Sphinx returned array and weight.

Tags: php, arrays, sphinx

I'm trying to simply echo the weight that is returned and doing something very wrong.

Here is the sample returned data:
    Array
    (
        [error] => 
        [warning] => 
        [status] => 0
        [fields] => Array
          (
            [0] => phrase
          )
       [attrs] => Array
        (
        )

```
   [matches] => Array
     (
        [34] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 1707
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

So here is the working code to get the id. This makes sense to me..

```
      if ( ! empty($result["matches"]) ) {
      foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {
            echo "DOC ID:$doc\n";
      }

      print_r( $result );
  }
```

I've tried another foreach  using the doc id to then loop through and get the weight..

```
foreach $doc as $weight  {
```

that doesnt work.  I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong here with the multidimension array but I'm not exactly sure how address the nested array..

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to return `weight` parameter from multilevel array ?

Comment: No.. The data structure is  there. I just am trying to get the value of 1707.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to try recursive function

```
$array =array(
    "matches" => array(
        array("weight"=>1707,"attrs"=>array("weight"=>100)),
        array("weight"=>1700,"attrs"=>array("weight"=>170)),
        array("weight"=>10,"attrs"=>array("weight"=>170,"attr"=>array("weight"=>"something other")))
    )
);

function recurse($array){
    foreach ($array as $arr){
        if (is_array($arr)){
            recurse($arr);
        } else {
            echo $arr . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

recurse($array);
```

`Note`: This function will return every `weight` parameter value from any level array

**UPDATED**

If you want to output just `weight` parameter value from the following array , try this

```
$array =array(
    "matches" => array(
        array("weight"=>1707,"attrs"=>"other param"),
        array("weight"=>1700,"attrs"=>"something other too"),
    )
);

foreach($array['matches'] as $arr){
    echo $arr['weight'] . "<br>";
}
```